# Executing a system command in Haskell

Tags: haskell, process, system

How could I execute a system command such as `cp somefile somedestination` in Haskell?

Something like an `os.Exec`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713448/haskell-execute-external-commands-in-strict-sequence

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Haskell 98 standard provides:

```hs
System.system :: String
              -> IO GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode
```

which executes a command.

The new [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process) library is more useful though, allowing for portable input/output redirection and so forth.

Comment: Note if you actually wish to copy a file you should use [copyfile](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+FilePath+-%3E+FilePath+-%3E+IO+%28%29).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Is there something unsafe about calling out to `cp`, or is `copyfile` just simpler?

Comment: @amindfv It's a portability issue.  How do you know the `cp` command is correct for your current platform?  How do you know the binary is in the path?  Etc, etc.

Comment: I couldn't resolve this function. What sort of import or qualification is needed? I ended up using `System.Cmd.system`

Comment: That's definitely not a complete example.

Answer (score 12):

```hs
import System.Process

main = callCommand "cp somefile somedestination"
```

just works, but you may prefer other functions from the `System.Process` module.

Comment: I think it's runCommand (I got `Not in scope: \`callCommand'`)

Comment: nope, `callCommand` is correct - `runCommand` does something different

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a haskell buff, but [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.0.1.1/doc/html/System-Process.html) may be what you're looking for

Comment: Put a complete example on the answer alongside the link...

Answer (score 2):

If you do this sort of thing a lot then it's worth having a look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HSH.