# Haskell not executing all external shell commands

Tags: shell, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

**I wrote this program and I compiled with:**

```
ghc --make shell.hs
```

**When I run it looks like:**

```
$./shell
enter your number:
6
6
okay... it execute 6 time...
```

If I remove the `sleep 2` statement then it exits fast but outputs only `6`.

I tried to follow the advice (which is what is in the code below) given [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713739/4725700) of a similar question but it didn't work.

It seems very strange that it is not executing all the commands. How do I force it to execute all commands and in a strict order? the lazyness is a good feature but when it comes to *IO* it just sucks or I am not enough of an expert to understand it.

What I want to do is execute all commands from a list in a strict order and I don't want *Haskell* to "intelligently" remove some of the commands on my behalf (if I want to execute sleep for 2 seconds in the shell, I should be allowed to do so).

If `waitForProcess` has to be used to resolve this, then my problem is I don't know how to use it. I have tried google but failed to see a simple example of it.

Please note that I want a working code solution for the program code I have given below and there should be a reasonable guarantee that the program works as expected on bash running on a typical Linux (say, Debian 7) as the *Python* program given below it runs.

```
import System.Process
import System.Exit

main = do
 putStrLn "enter your number:"
 n <- getLine
 main1 (readInt n)
 putStrLn ("okay... it execute " ++ n ++" time...")

readInt:: String -> Int
readInt = read

main1 n = do
 ExitSuccess <- system ("echo " ++ (show n))
 ExitSuccess <- system "sleep 2"
 if n == 0 then (main1 (n-1)) else return ()
```

**Below is a *Python* program and it works as desired with proper `sleep`:**

```
import os
for i in range(6):
  os.system("echo " + str(i))
  os.system("sleep 2")
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that your ``if then else`` phrase seems wrong. Try swapping the then expression with the else expression. You want to return when n==0... Of course you could also split it up using pattern matching: ``main1 0 = do return(); main1 n = do ExitSuccess <- system (...); main1 (n-1);``

Comment: There are nicer ways to write this, but the only real problem is the the test in your loop is wrong. You want something like `n > 1` rather than `n == 0`.

Comment: @BitTickler thanks a lot. it works fine. sorry for the trouble. I accept your suggestion as answer turn it into answer.

Comment: A note on your python program: you *should* avoid `os.system`. Use `subprocess.call` instead: `from subprocess import call; call(['echo', str(i)]); call(['sleep', '2'])`. When (and only when) you need shell features you can pass `shell=True` to `call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about writing more like the Python version using `forM_`:

```
import Control.Monad

main1 n = do
  forM_ [n,n-1 .. 1] $ \n -> do
    ExitSuccess <- system ("echo " ++ (show n))
    ExitSuccess <- system "sleep 2"
    return ()
```

Comment: Why count down? The Python program looks like it counts up.

Comment: The original Haskell program counts down, that's all. I just wanted to point out how to use a `forM_` loop - just like you would do in Python - instead of using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The program is doing what you are telling him to do:

```
main1 n = do
 ExitSuccess <- system ("echo " ++ (show n))
 ExitSuccess <- system "sleep 2"
 if n == 0 then (main1 (n-1)) else return ()
```

Here we have `n == 6` so the condition of the `if` is false and then `return ()` is executed, which terminates `main1` doing nothing.

Note that if you passed `n == 0` the condition would be true and it would execute `main1 (-1)` which then stops. In any case `main1` will **not** repeat the commands `n` times it will always either execute them once (if `n /= 0`) or twice (if `n == 0`).

You could fix this by doing:

```
main1 n = do
 ExitSuccess <- system ("echo " ++ (show n))
 ExitSuccess <- system "sleep 2"
 if n > 0 then main1 (n-1) else return ()
```

Or, equivalently:

```
import Control.Monad

main1 n = do
 ExitSuccess <- system ("echo " ++ (show n))
 ExitSuccess <- system "sleep 2"
 when (n > 0) $ main1 (n-1)
```

The problem here is that you are using general recursion to repeat a given statement. But general recursion can do anything and so you can easily produce bugs (as in your case). To avoid this it's often useful to use some other function to build your code. For example:

```
main1 n = sequence_ $ map execute [1..n]

execute i = do
  ExitSuccess <- system $ "echo" ++ show i
  ExitSuccess <- system $ "sleep 2"
  return ()
```

Or:

```
main1 n = mapM_ execute [1..n]
```

Here you know what `mapM_` and `[1..n]` do and so combining them tells you that you the `execute` action will be executed `n` times.

---

In any case the `IO` monad *guarantees* the the actions are all executed and in order, so you should not attribute to Haskell lazyness the fact that the code wasn't executed the expected number of times.

The problem with lazyness and input/output are different.