# How to invoke bash or shell scripts from a haskell program?

Tags: shell, haskell, ffi

I'm writing some shell scripts with haskell, which I'm running in gitbash, but there are a few other existing scripts I'd like to be able to use from those scripts.

For example, I'd like to run maven goals or do a git pull, but without having to integrate specifically with those tools.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: yes, and asynchronously https://github.com/friedbrice/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-fetch.hs :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing a system command in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470955/executing-a-system-command-in-haskell)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`System.Process`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process/docs/System-Process.html).
For example, executing `seq 1 10` shell command:

```
> import System.Process

> readProcess "seq" ["1", "10"] ""
"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n"
it :: String

> readProcessWithExitCode  "seq" ["1", "10"] ""
(ExitSuccess,"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n","")
it :: (GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode, String, String)
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `process` package, which exports many useful functions. Simplest one is `System.Cmd.system`, which can run some application in shell, yielding exit code.

More advanced features are provided too in the `System.Process` module. With this module you can run process and communicate with it in many ways (input piping, exit codes, waiting for process to stop, modify its environment etc).

Answer (score 7):

Of course. You can start by using [system](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.0.1.3/doc/html/System-Cmd.html) to invoke external processes.

More sophisticated piping and process control is available in a cross-platform way from the [System.Process](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.0.1.3/doc/html/System-Process.html) library.

Finally, you can consider porting your shell scripts to Haskell, [via shell DSLs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shellish/0.1.4/doc/html/Shellish.html).

Answer (score 7):

[Turtle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle/docs/Turtle-Tutorial.html) is pretty nice modern haskell library for this.