# Stack Build within Haskell

Tags: haskell-stack

I want to be able to call stack from within haskell to build a project for me. Nothing in the documentation explains this and going through `src/main/Main.hs` has been difficult to understand what function is the correct to use.

CLI version of what I want to run with imported stack functions:

```
stack build --fast
```

Explicitly not using calls to bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to invoke bash or shell scripts from a haskell program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536614/is-it-possible-to-invoke-bash-or-shell-scripts-from-a-haskell-program)

Comment: I don't want to leave haskell to do this. I would like to use functions imported from the stack package.