# Execute shell script from a POST request with scotty

Tags: haskell, post, scotty

I'm using scotty and I'm getting the same type error any way I try to execute a shell script from a POST request.

```
main = scotty 3000 $ do    
  post "MyPage/ScriptTime/run" $ do
      aparameter <- param "aparameter"
      bparameter <- param "bparameter"
      cparameter <- param "cparameter"
      dparameter <- param "dparameter"
      eparameter <- param "eparameter"
      rawSystem "./shellscript.sh" [ "-a"
                                   , aparameter
                                   , "-b"
                                   , bparameter
                                   , "-c"
                                   , cparameter
                                   , dparameter
                                   , eparameter
                                   ]
```

Using the answers on [Is it possible to invoke bash or shell scripts from a haskell program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536614/is-it-possible-to-invoke-bash-or-shell-scripts-from-a-haskell-program) and [Executing a system command in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470955/executing-a-system-command-in-haskell) have not helped me change the error message.

The error reads:

```
Main.hs:68:5: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘IO’
                 with ‘Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                         Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO’
  Expected type: Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                   Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO ()
    Actual type: IO GHC.IO.Exception.ExitCode
• In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    rawSystem "./shellscript.sh" ["-a", aparameter, "-b", bparameter, ....]
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘do aparameter <- param "aparameter"
        bparameter <- param "bparameter"
        cparameter <- param "cparameter"
        dparameter <- param "dparameter"
        ....’
```

I've changed the function and library used for invoking the shell script several ways, including:

`() <- createProcess (proc "./shellscript.sh" ["-a", aparameter, "-b", bparameter, ...])`

`runProcess (shell "./shellscript.sh -a aparameter -b bparameter ...") >>= print`

I have tried using System.Process, System.Process.Typed, and System.Cmd libraries.

Can someone help me understand my type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mismatch is in the monad in which the functions run. `rawSystem` runs in the `IO` monad, as indicated by [its type](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.16/process-1.6.5.0/System-Cmd.html#v:rawSystem), as well as in the error message. But `scotty`'s `run` function expects a thing that runs in the [`ActionT e m` monad](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.16/scotty-0.11.5/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ActionT).

The error message tells you as much: *cannot match type `IO _` with `ActionT Text IO _`*.

Since `ActionT` has an instance of `MonadTrans`, you can just [`lift`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.16/transformers-0.5.6.2/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) an `IO` function into `ActionT _ IO`:

```
lift $ rawSystem "./shellscript.sh" [...]
```

After you have done that, your next problem will be the return type: `rawSystem` returns an `ExitCode`, while `scotty`'s `run` function expects unit. If you're ok just throwing away the exit code (though I don't recomment it), you can either bind it to an unnamed variable:

```
_ <- lift $ rawSystem ...
pure ()
```

Or, better yet, you can use [`void`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.16/base-4.12.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:void) to discard the value:

```
void . lift $ rawSystem ...
```

Comment: Amazing. By the way, `_ <- lift $ rawSystem ...` produces an error "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression". However, `void . lift $ rawSystem ...` works perfectly.

Comment: That is why I also added `pure ()`. You must have glanced over it.

Comment: That appears exactly to be what happened. Thanks!